Need help parsing a sentence involving 下らない
From 若き時代の道:

サラリーマンの生活の下らない、希望のなさ、その日暮しの味気なさについて流行歌まであるのだが、若いサラリーマンたちが、自分たちの生活の無意味さを自嘲的に喋るところだけに、自分のインテリゲンツィアである微かな誇りをもっていることが、私には本当に口惜しい気がする。

I have difficulty understanding the first part of the sentence. Commas are not working in my favor. I am uncertain whether 下らない modifies 希望のなさ both その日暮しの味気なさ or 希望のなさ only. If it is the latter, その日暮し refers to day-to-day life of a salaryman devoid of hope?

So I think you're asking which is correct between:

下らない希望のなさ + その日暮しの味気なさ
下らない × (希望のなさ + その日暮しの味気なさ)

Both interpretations are possible, but I feel the first interpretation is more straightforward. Either way, her use of commas is indeed somewhat confusing.
(サラリーマンの生活の)下らない希望のなさ would mean "damned hopelessness (of a salaryman's life)" and (サラリーマンの生活の)その日暮しの味気なさ would mean "the monotony of living day to day".
